# ggplot: some Unicode shapes working while others do not

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode

Here's a simple example.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape="\u2620", size = 8)
```

This works perfectly to create skull and crossbones as the shapes, as [2620 is the hex value for this unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2620/index.htm). I actually want the [elephant shape, which has the hex code 1F418](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f418/index.htm).

However, substituting 1F418 for 2620 produces the error message

> Error: Can't find shape name:
>   * '8'

Why does the elephant shape not work? How can I get the elephant shape to appear in my plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lower case `\u` escape prefix represents Unicode characters with 16-bit hex values.  For 32-bit hex values use the upper case `\U` or a surrogate pair (two 16-bit values):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape="\U1F418", size = 8) # is "\U0001f418"
```

Or:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape="\uD83D\uDC18", size = 8)
```

[image]